# EXT JS multiple commits at one time

Tags: extjs

I am trying to do a group commit in EXTJS. I know you can use the store.add() with an array of models however it just calls the POST web service multiple times. Does anyone know a best practice or if this is even possible? I am using JPA/hibernate on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is, i don't know your store-model config but you can do it by configuring

```
autoSync: false, batchUpdateMode: 'complete'
```

on your store, and:

```
batchActions: true
```

on your proxy and calling `sync()` after you finnished adding records to the store.

Comment: well... this is basically doing what I already had on the front end. calling the store add only once which I was already doing but it is still calling the POST web service separately for each object. @VoidMain do you know to link this up with the back end so it only needs one call.

Comment: Updated my answer, you just need to add `batchActions: true` to your proxy config.